# How to setup nginx to site to a Django app over https?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, ssl

I have an application that I am running with multiple docker containers with a docker-compose file. Two main containers are `django_container` and `nginx_container`.

I want to force using `https` for my application but unfortunately, my Nginx config doesn't seem to work. Basically, my gunicorn server seems to be running OK.

I can see the `http://django:8001` from inside the `nginx_container`, but I can't see `http://example.com` from inside it or outside.

Here is the content of my Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

    access_log  /log/nginx.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://django:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

To create the containers I use the following `docker-compose.yml` file, which read the values from the corresponding `.env` file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
        postgres:
                image: postgres:13.0
                container_name: postgres_container
                restart: always
                ports:
                       - "5432:5432"
                volumes:
                       - $P_VOLUME:/initdb.d/
                environment:
                       P_USER: $P_USER                
                       P_PASSWORD: $P_PASSWORD
                       P_DB: $P_DB
        django:
                build: 
                        context: .
                        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
                container_name: django_container
                depends_on: 
                        - postgres
                ports:
                        - "8001:8001"
                volumes:
                        - $ROOT_DIR:/code/
                environment:
                        SECRET_KEY: $SECRET_KEY
                        ROOT_DIR: $ROOT_DIR
        nginx:
                image: nginx
                container_name: nginx_container
                depends_on: 
                        - django
                ports:
                        - "80:80"
                        - "443:443"
                environment:
                        NGINX_HOST: $NGINX_HOST
                        NGINX_PORT: 80
                volumes:
                        - $ROOT_DIR/config/$NGINX_CONF:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
                        - $ROOT_DIR/log/:/log/
                        - $ROOT_DIR/certs/:/etc/nginx/certs/
```

I checked the `.env` file and it seems the paths and configs are correct.

What am I missing here? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Show your `docker-compose.yml` file, please.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IvanShatsky for helping me out. I modified the original question to include it. The .env file seems correct, but please let me know if you'd like to see that too.

Thanks!